# How to launch a separate Excel application each time I open an "*.xlsm" file

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, file-association, file-extension

As stated in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021515/all-excel-sheets-are-not-responding-while-executing-macro-from-other-excel-fil), I would like to open a new Excel application every time I open an `*.xlsm` file. I know this can be done launching `Excel /x` from the start button, but I'd like to use the `/x` when opening the mentioned file extension.

I already know I need the `Assoc` and `FType` commands for this, but it seems not to work. My current settings are:

```
Prompt>Assoc .xlsm
.xlsm=Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12
Prompt>ftype Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12
Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "%1"
```

I already tried adding the "`/x`" switch as follows:

```
...\EXCEL.EXE /x" "%1"
...\EXCEL.EXE" "/x" "%1"
...\EXCEL.EXE" "/x %1"
```

I've already tried launching Excel, using this command prompt, and it's working, so I should be close:

```
Prompt>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /x C:\Temp_Folder\tralala.xlsm
```

Does anybody know how I can get this done?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900659/how-to-open-excel-macro-files-xlsm-in-separate-instances-of-excel-2016-win10

Comment: @Lee: thanks for your reply, but this seems not to be working: the post is the registry equivalent of the mentioned `assoc` and `ftype` commands and actually removes the `ftype` entry. As a result my "*.xlsm" files don't open anymore. I'm more interested in how to modify the `ftype` (how to add the `/x` switch).